# Exposing and importing a data constructor from another module

Tags: elm

In my Elm program I want to define a type in one module:

MyModule.elm:

```
module MyModule exposing (MyType)
type MyType = Constr1 String | Constr2 Int
```

and construct a value of this type in another module:

Main.elm:

```
import MyModule exposing (MyType)
import Html exposing (text)
main =
    let x = Constr1 "foo" in
        text "hello"
```

When I build this with:

```
elm-package install elm-lang/html && elm-make Main.elm
```

I get:

```
NAMING ERROR ------------------------------------------------------- Main.elm

Cannot find variable `Constr1`

6|     let x = Constr1 "foo" in
               ^^^^^^^


Detected errors in 1 module.
```

If I use `(..)` in both `exposing` clauses, this compiles fine, but I would like to know how to express that I want to expose the constructors.

Side note: I would also like to know where I should have found this in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify which constructors to expose like this:

```elm
module MyModule exposing (MyType(Constr1, Constr2))
```

All constructors of a type can be exposed using `(..)` notation:

```elm
module MyModule exposing (MyType(..))
```

And if you don't want to expose any constructors (meaning you have other exposed functions that create values of your type, you specify only the type:

```elm
module MyModule exposing (MyType, otherFunctions)
```

There is community documentation around this topic at [elm-community.github.io/elm-faq](http://elm-community.github.io/elm-faq/#why-when-i-import-a-module-that-defines-a-type-does-the-compiler-know-about-the-type-name-but-not-its-constructors)

Comment: I'll add it to the community docs so it [shows up here](http://elm-community.github.io/elm-faq/#why-when-i-import-a-module-that-defines-a-type-does-the-compiler-know-about-the-type-name-but-not-its-constructors)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  I'll go and read about why I shouldn't do this.